# ListView items not displaying in android tabbed fragment activity

Tags: listview, android-studio, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I can't figure out what's wrong with the code that the items on my list view on a fragment that is called from a Tabbed activity are not displaying any items from my string array.

I have set the background of the text view and the list view to see if it has actually been displayed, and it does. I can see the textview at the top and the yellow background of the list view below.

**fragment_display_questions.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="layout.DisplayQuestionsFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:background="#ffff00"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="333dp"
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="#ffff00"
        android:layout_marginTop="156dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the java code in the onCreate method of **DisplayQuestionsFragment.java**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display_questions, container, false);

    String[] questions={"Question 1","Question 2"};


    ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);

    ArrayAdapter<String> listviewadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            questions
    );

    lv.setAdapter(listviewadapter);

    return view;
}
```

There is no error return it's just that the items aren't there in the list view. Please help and give some inputs.

Thank you very much!

Comment: call another override method ÓnViewCreated and put your code inside it and try

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
```

Note: One thing should be noted that instead of using String Array use String arraylist it may solve the issue once and for all.